# Is this intention permissible?

Tags: allah, ibadah, niyyah

Can I have the intention while doing and kind of a good deed or worship that I would like to do it for the sake of Allah ﷻ, seek the reward and to get closer to Allah ﷻ. Thank you

Comment: In fact if you did it for any other reason it hardly would be accepted or only count for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without a doubt, it is good to have the intention to do good. Unlike concepts in Brahman religions (e.g. Buddhism), Islam clearly favourises us to actively live our faith, try to follow the Commandments of God as good as we can and to do good. There are plenty of passages in the Holy Quran I may cite; I select this longer section because it concerns many aspects:

Al-Baqarah 2:269-274

> He gives wisdom to whomever He wills. Whoever is given wisdom has been
> given much good. But none pays heed except those with insight.
> Whatever charity you give, or a pledge you fulfill, God knows it. The
> wrongdoers have no helpers. If you give charity openly, that is good.
> But if you keep it secret, and give it to the needy in private, that
> is better for you. It will atone for some of your misdeeds. God is
> cognizant of what you do.
> Their guidance is not your responsibility, but God guides whom He
> wills. Any charity you give is for your own good. Any charity you give
> shall be for the sake of God. Any charity you give will be repaid to
> you in full, and you will not be wronged. It is for the poor; those
> who are restrained in the way of God, and unable to travel in the
> land. The unaware would think them rich, due to their dignity. You
> will recognize them by their features. They do not ask from people
> insistently. Whatever charity you give, God is aware of it. Those who
> spend their wealth by night and day, privately and publicly, will
> receive their reward from their Lord. They have nothing to fear, nor
> shall they grieve.

The first is : «He gives wisdom to whomever He wills. Whoever is given wisdom has been given much good.»

Yes, God gives to whom He wills. But He will always encourage to follow and reward those who really do His commmandments.

If you seek to do His commmandments (it need not be charity if you are not rich enough, there are plenty of other virtues) and feel that you like to do so, this will move you closer to God, and He promised you to guide you.

So everything is fine.